# Regex to find all dollar signs and parentheses and commas

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex to remove all instances of dollar signs, commas, and opening and closing parentheses so that the String can be parsed to a Double.

Exmaples are:

```
($108.34)
$39.60
1,388.80
```

The code:

```
@Parsed
@Replace(expression = "", replacement = "")
public Double extdPrice;
```

Comment: It would be more to the point to remove everything except the digits, the decimal point, and the sign. But in accounting a number in parentheses is negative, and you need to know that when converting. And as this is clearly money you should be using `BigDecimal`, not `Double`.

Comment: @user207421 The problem is that the `@Replace` annotation is not repeatable and the value will be inserted into MongoDB, so `Double` has to be used.

Comment: Then the table definition is wrong too. It should be `DECIMAL(10,2)` or so. Don't underestimate the seriousness of this error. I doubt you can do it with a single regular expression for the reason I stated.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Expression = `[^0-9\\.]`

is what you are looking for. It will match anything other than digits `0-9` and character `.`

So technically this regex will remove all extra characters like `(` `,` `$` `USD` and etc

Example: `System.out.println("($123.89)".replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", ""));` will give an output `123.89`

**Test output:**

- ($108.34) => 108.34
- $39.60 => 39.60
- 1,388.80 => 1388.80

Answer (score 0):

This may help, we delete all the elements in this list: , $ ( )

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "[(),$]";
        final String string = "($108.34)\n"
     + "$39.60\n"
     + "1,388.80";
        final String subst = "";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
        
        System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d{1,3}(\,\d\d\d)*(\.\d+)?`
can match all number like your examples, but it can't match 123456(no comma).
result was

```
108.34
39.60
1,388.80
```

and you need replace comma